# Getting Exception system.reflection.targetinvocationexception exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

```
 public void Post_To_Set_Location_Header_Build()
    {
        // This version uses a mock UrlHelper.
        var mockRepository = new Mock<SEFDataServiceRequestManager>();

        var controller = new BuildController(mockRepository.Object);

        BuildStatusResult buildStatus=null ;
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage() { Properties = { { HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration() } } }; 
        // Act

        HttpResponseMessage actionResult = controller.Post(buildStatus);
        Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, actionResult.StatusCode);



    }
```

> I have some unit testcases in a cs file of webAPI when i run tescases it shows the exception as below
>
> system.reflection.targetinvocationexception exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation -->System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Your question is missing some information that would make it a lot easier to diagnose your problem, like which line in the test is throwing the null reference exception, what is your expected behaviour?, what does your BuildController function do?, etc.. What exactly is your question?  Generally if your question lacks a question mark, you have probably missed something important.

Comment: var mockRepository = new Mock<SEFDataServiceRequestManager>(); in this line the exception is showing.

Comment: SEFDataServiceRequestManager _repository;

        public BuildController()
        {
            _repository = new SEFDataServiceRequestManager();
        }
        public BuildController(SEFDataServiceRequestManager repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
       
       
        public string  Get()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
this is my build controller